# If $f\circ g = |\sin x|$ and $g\circ f = \sin^2\sqrt{x}$ then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are?

Tags: functions

> If $ f\circ g = |\sin x|$ and $g\circ f = \sin^2\sqrt{x}$ then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are:

Thanks

Akash

Comment: no not any i only know i can write $fog = \sqrt{sin^2x}$

Comment: Okay, so what happens to the root when you switch $f$ and $g$? $$ \sqrt{\sin^2 x}\to\sin^2{\sqrt x} $$

Comment: Tell me what functions you see, and take a wild guess at what $f$ and $g$ might be (hint: you'll probably be right)

Comment: maybe g(x)=x^2 and f(x)=sin(sqrt(x))

Comment: no, but close.  that gets $f(g(x))=\sin x$

Comment: What if you make $f(x)=\sqrt x$?

Comment: $f = \sqrt x$ and $g = \sin^2 x$ works.

Comment: @Tim Ratigan ok solution is in my book and it is same as you said but i am getting stuck at how $\sqrt{g(x)} = \sqrt{sin^2x}$ can you explain it in detail and a much simpler way

Comment: In general $\sqrt{u^2}=|u|$ for any real number $u$.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm going to put everything from the comments into one answer because that's where it belongs.

First, you notice that $|\sin x|=\sqrt{\sin^2 x}$ (which OP noticed on their own).

This means that $f(g(x))=\sqrt{\sin^2 x}$ and $g(f(x))=\sin^2\sqrt x$

Since $\sqrt x$ moves inside and outside of $\sin^2x$ as we rearrange the functions, it's reasonable to assume that $f(x)=\sqrt x$.  Then we solve for $g(x)$:

$$\begin{align} f(g(x))=\sqrt{g(x)}&=|\sin x|\\
g(x)&=\sin^2 x \end{align}$$

Now, to check our answer, we see $g(f(x))=\sin^2 f(x)=\sin^2\sqrt x$, which agrees with the original problem, so we're done!

Comment: so we will have to assume that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ there is other way to find it because this is where i got stuck

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to prove the functional equation but that would require much more thought and effort than is needed for this problem. @Akash